# My file corrupt when using db connection

Tags: php, mysql

I have a download script which get id of file and search in database and find it's name. But when I include my db connection the files get corrupted on download.
when I comment my db connection and give file name manually file downloading work fine.
I test my db connection and there wasn't any excpetion or any html output , what do you think my problem is?

```
 <?php
session_start();
try{
  $db= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname","user","pass");
  $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
  $db->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
}catch (Exception $e){
 //echo "something wrong in db.php";
 echo $e->getMessage();
 exit;
}
?>
```

I run my code on windows server IIS, if it does matter

Comment: [`catch ( PDOException $e )`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php) - then tell us your error, read the documentation.

Comment: @KDOT still there isn't any exception

Comment: Then doesn't this tell you that you have no issue in this file? Turn on error reporting and update your question with the error and the code causing the error

Comment: @KDOT there isn't any error on my log file about connection. and also my database query give data but I don't know why it's corrupt file. as you know this kind of corruption should be result of outputing something.
It's add unexpected charecter to file, for example txt file

Answer (score 0):

**Just try with this code..**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','1'); 
   $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
    $user = 'dbuser';
    $password = 'dbpass';

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

**It will return your error.**

Comment: Can I ask you, Why this answer downvote before any testing.

Comment: Its ok.. Did you try with my code..Its not your fault.. some guys on stackoverflow dont know rules of stackoverflow

Comment: @peyman I have check your code.. and its working fine.. Can you please check at your server mysql extension loaded or not in php.ini .

Comment: what extension kumar? as I sayed before my db connection work and I can query, But I don't understand why with including my db connection file, my downloaded file get corrupt

Answer (score 0):

after few days struggling and headache finaly problem resolved by deleting try catch block